# Webpack: How to get relative path in css sourcemap

Tags: css, webpack, source-maps, css-loader

I'm using mac, chrome 69, webpack 3.8.1, css-loader 1.0.0, style-loader 0.19.1

I have css sourcemap set up like this in my webpack config:

```
test: /\.css$/,
use: [
  {
    loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
    options: {
      sourceMap: true
    }
  },

  {
    loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
    options: {
      importLoaders: 1,
      sourceMap: true
    },
  },
```

And in chrome devTool element inspector, it looks like this:

[image]

The question is, is it possible to shorten the source map to be relative to my project root path?

So instead of `/Users/xunyang/workspace/myProject/src/index.css`

I'd like it to be displayed as `/src/index.css`

With some experimenting, looks like the css sourcemap is independent from webpack devtool sourcemap, so I'd imagine css-loader is the most likely place for it to happen.

**Update** My publicPath is '/' and publicUrl is ''. The configuration is taken directly from Create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

try `convertToAbsoluteUrls : false` option along with

> Converts relative URLs to absolute urls, when source maps are enabled
>
> If convertToAbsoluteUrls and sourceMaps are both enabled, relative
>   urls will be converted to absolute urls right before the css is
>   injected into the page.

Ref : https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#converttoabsoluteurls

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { 
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              convertToAbsoluteUrls: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: true,
              convertToAbsoluteUrls: false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```